# How to select only the first element matching a descendant CSS class

Tags: html, css

I need to target a descendant class (let's call it `inner`) of an `outer` class, but *only* the first element with the `inner` class (which is not outer's first child). An arbitrary number of elements and levels of nesting may appear prior to the first occurrence of `inner` inside `outer`, and after that `inner` may (re)appear multiple times. A simplified HTML structure follows (with my failed attempt to use `:nth-child()`:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    
        <style>
            .outer :nth-child(1 of .inner) {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="outer">
        <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
        <div>
            <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
            <div class="inner">
                <span>Should BE affected!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
        <div>
          <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
          <div>
            <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
            <div class="inner">
                <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

In this example `inner` appears only twice, but it can appear multiple times.

I can't control the HTML generated, all I can do is add the `.outer` class to the outer div (the `inner` class actually is added by the control rendering library I'm using, which I don't *control* - no pun intended).

So I need to target this "first" `inner` element, and ignore all other instances of it. Am I approaching this the wrong (CSS) way? How can I achieve that?

Comment: If this is static HTML, can you just add the class (or a new class) to the correct place? If this is dynamically built HTML, can you codify this logic to set the class correctly?

Comment: @PAB I've stated in the question that I can't change the generated HTML. It's generation is opaque to me. All I can do is stick the `outer` class to the outer container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to an element that contains `.inner`, namely `.outer > *:has(.inner)`.
Let's call it `EL`. Then І provided some explanations in the code comments:

```css
.outer {
  --color: black;
  color: var(--color);
}

/* we find .inner in EL */
.outer > *:has(.inner) .inner {
  color: red;
}

/* .inner children and subsequent-sibling */
.inner .inner,
.inner ~ .inner {
  color: var(--color)!important;
}

/* EL's children which has .inner */
.outer > *:has(.inner) > *:has(.inner) .inner {
  color: var(--color);
}

/* EL's subsequent-sibling which has .inne */
.outer > *:has(.inner) ~ *:has(.inner) .inner {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Should BE affected!</span>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Should NOT be affected</span>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works with the sample markup but didn't work in my real markup. Since it's very well commented, I'm trying to adapt it to work in the real scenario! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect scenario for the (experimental) [`@scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@scope) rule. This limits (in this case) inline styles to the scope of where they are placed. And so:

You'll want to check [the browser coverage for browsers you support](https://caniuse.com/css-cascade-scope).

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <style>
        @scope {
          .inner {
            color: red;
          }
        }
      </style>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should BE affected!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div>
        <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
        <div class="inner">
          <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can use JavaScript to insert the style node. You could also use JavaScript to set the style attribute on the node itself, as another answer does, but I was demonstrating the use of `@scope` in this answer.

```js
const se = document.createElement('style');
se.textContent = '@scope { .inner { color: red; } }';
document.querySelector(".outer").querySelector(".inner").insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', se);
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should BE affected!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div>
        <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
        <div class="inner">
          <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me... If I could add an inline style at this location, then I could just change the css class for the "first" `inner` element. This "container" HTML generation is opaque to me. All I can do is add the `outer` CSS class to the outermost container.

Comment: Sure, and you can use JavaScript to affect the DOM easily enough. There may be a way of using `@scope` more elegantly to get what you want also. I just wasn't able to find it before work called me back...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cant. `nth-child` will always select from its own parent container not other parents or ancestors. You need JavaScript.

jQuery has a process (`.first`) for your requirement

```js
$(".inner").first().css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Should BE affected!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the only actual solution to the problem! I'll wait for  more input before selecting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You select the first direct descendant that has at least one `.inner` element. Then inside that element you select the `.inner` that has no `.inner` element as parent and no `.inner` elements before it (within the same parent)

This won't cover all the cases but maybe it's enough for you.

```css
.outer > div:nth-child(1 of div:has(.inner)) .inner:not(.inner *):not(.inner ~ *) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Should BE affected!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, a pure CSS solution seems to heavy to find. So indeed you need javascript, but not necessarily jQuery.

- You can create a CSS class for the `first-inner` to set the color.
- You make a `document.querySelector(".inner")`, which is going to
  target the first element only
- You add `first-inner` to its `classList`.

```js
document.querySelector(".inner").classList.add("first-inner")
```

```css
.first-inner {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Should BE affected!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
  <div>
    <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
    <div>
      <!-- Arbitrary number of elements may happen here -->
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Should NOT be affected!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the preced selector in order to affect all of the elements after the first one.

Could you try this, please:

```
<style>
    .outer {
        color:red;
    }

    div:first-of-type ~ div  {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "preced" selector. There's the [subsequent-sibling selector (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator) which you appear to be using. You can "try this" yourself using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/), which you can create in your answer.